# Получение файлов на фронте с сервера(изображений)

Tags: reactjs, изображения, download

Сервер отдает нам файлы изображений загруженных ранее с другого места приложения.

Делаю запрос, в ответе приходит вот такое полотно текста[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мне необходимо это изображение вставить в тег img, ну типо отобразить как аватаку на странице, и у меня ничего не получатся или я тупой или что?
Пытался вот так

```
    const { data: avatar, isLoading: isAvatarLoading } = useGetAvatarSource();

    const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
      if (avatar) {
          var imageDataUri = URL.createObjectURL(avatar);
          setImageUrl(imageDataUri);
        }
     }, [avatar]);
```

но браузер выкидывает ошибку:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.
```

Comment: Что вам приходит в avatar? Подозреваю, что надо то, что пришло с сервера, превратить в Blob

Comment: @SwaD да я понимаю чтоб его обработать во что мне его надо превратить, просто я не совсем уверен что мне приходит... На console.log(avatar) выводится то что на скрине, как будто файл изображения открыли в блокноте о_О. По идее мне должен приходить файл, но приходит как будто что то не то

Comment: Попробуйте что то вроде `const avatarBlob = new Blob(avatar); setImageUrl(avatarBlob)`

Comment: @SwaD не подходит такой вариант, код падает с ошибкой:

    "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'Blob': The provided value cannot be converted to a sequence."